# nested div display and hide on dropdown value selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open drop down and other fields on the basis of others. I am trying to create a form for clients to fill their form with specific requirement.

The DIV will hide and show on the basis of dropdown selected using jquery.

Here is how my html code looks like.

```
<div class="website-type">
                <label class=""><b>Website Type</b>
                    <select>
                        <option>--------Select--------</option>
                        <option value="static-website">Static Website</option>
                        <option value="dynamic-website">Dynamic Website</option>
                        <option value="ecommerce-website">eCommerce Website</option>
                        <option value="seo">Search Engine Optimization</option>
                        <option value="graphic-design">Graphic Design</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="static-website" id="static-website">

                    <label class=""><b>Design Level</b>
                        <select>
                                <option>--------Select--------</option>
                                <option value="basic-design">Basic Design</option>
                                <option value="business-design">Business Design</option>
                                <option value="creative-design">Creative Design</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                     <br/>



                <div class="static-website-basic">

                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of Basic Static Box -->



                 <div class="static-website-business">



                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="10" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="10" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of BUSINESS Static Box -->



                 <div class="static-website-creative">



                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of Creative Static Box -->


            </div> <!-- End of Static Box -->
```

This is just a regular jquery i am using. Here is how i am using my jquery

```
$("select").change(function()
        {
            $( "select option:selected").each(function()
            {
                if($(this).attr("value")=="static-website"){
                    $(".dynamic-website").hide();
                    $(".ecommerce-website").hide();
                    $(".seo").hide();
                    $(".graphic-design").hide();
                    $(".static-website").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="basic-design"){
                    $(".static-website-business")..hide();
                    $(".static-website-creative").hide();


                    $(".static-website-basic").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="business-design"){
                     $(".static-website-basic").hide();
                    $(".static-website-creative").hide();
                    $(".static-website-business").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="creative-design"){
                     $(".static-website-basic").hide();
                    $(".static-website-business").hide();
                    $(".static-website-creative").show();

                    ​
                } 

}

});
        }).change();
    });
```

I dont want so many .hide and .show property for every div. My one drop down is based on another and after selection of 2nd dropdown selection.

this is just of Static Website. Then i have several other fields. I dont know how can i do this. I dont want to make it very complicated i just want to make things simple and reusable so i dont have to use so many .hide and .show

If any suggestions. please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `.toggle()` ?

Comment: No it will be based on dropdown selection. So dependency will be on drop down. Suppose when i select "Basic Website" then DIV of "static-website-basic" should open. and rest all the div like "static-website-business" should  be hide if its field on showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better hiding and showing as required.

```js
var oldselected;
$("select").on('change',this,function(e){
  if(oldselected){$('.'+oldselected).hide();}
  var selectedopt=$(this).val();   
  $('.'+selectedopt).show();
  oldselected=selectedopt;
  });
```

```css
div:not(.website-type){display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="website-type">
                <label class=""><b>Website Type</b>
                    <select>
                        <option>--------Select--------</option>
                        <option value="static-website">Static Website</option>
                        <option value="dynamic-website">Dynamic Website</option>
                        <option value="ecommerce-website">eCommerce Website</option>
                        <option value="seo">Search Engine Optimization</option>
                        <option value="graphic-design">Graphic Design</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="static-website" id="static-website">

                    <label class=""><b>Design Level</b>
                        <select>
                                <option>--------Select--------</option>
                                <option value="basic-design">Basic Design</option>
                                <option value="business-design">Business Design</option>
                                <option value="creative-design">Creative Design</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                     <br/>



                <div class="static-website-basic">

                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of Basic Static Box -->



                 <div class="static-website-business">



                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="10" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="10" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of BUSINESS Static Box -->



                 <div class="static-website-creative">



                    <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>


                    <label class="no-form-static"><b>Number Of Simple Form</b>
                        <input type="text" name="no-form-static" value="5" />
                    </label>

                     <br/>

                    <label class="seo-static"><b>SEO (On Page)</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="seo-static" group="seo-static"> No

                    </label>

                    <br/>

                    <label class="content-writting-static"><b>Content Writing</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="content-static" group="content-writting-static"> No
                    </label>
                 </div><!-- End of Creative Static Box -->


            </div> <!-- End of Static Box -->
```

Comment: What should i do to hide?

Comment: just before `$('.'+selectedopt).show();` put `$('div').hide();` that will hide all divs then show the selected one

Comment: i tried that try the same on this link http://jsfiddle.net/a6kne66b/3/ i can not do that. i have lots of DIV in that.

Comment: do you want to hide each one on change? or is it that if someone changes an option again it resets?

Comment: no suppose i am selecting "Basic Design" then i want to hide Business Design and Creative design whatever details is opened.

Comment: No once i select suppose "Business Design" then i change it to "Basic Design" then the data do not hide.

Answer (score 1):

I built a quick utility to do this, it accepts a few data attributes...

**http://jsfiddle.net/buxbajvd/**

```
<form class="progressiveDisclosure">
    <select name="selectNode" class="associatedHandler">
        <option>foobar</option>
        <option>something</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div class="associatedListener" style="display: none;" data-for="selectNode" data-value="something" data-props="matchAll">selectNode is something</div>
```

The data-for must match the handlers name attribute and the data-value must match its value for this node to show. It can also accept multiple arguments `data-for="someSelect,someSelect2" data-value="someValue,someValue2"`

It is also possible to use reverse conditioning and setting `data-value="!someValue"`

```
var progressiveDisclosure = $('.progressiveDisclosure'),
    associatedHandlers = $('.associatedHandler'),
    associatedListeners = $('.associatedListener'),

    toggleAssociatedListeners = function(e){
        var name = $(e.target).attr('name');

        $.each(associatedListeners, function(index, node){

            var names = node.associationFor,
                values = node.associationValue,
                valid = false,
                matchAll = false;

            if(node.associationOpts && node.associationOpts.indexOf('matchAll') > -1){
                matchAll = true;
            }

            var inputIsAssociation = false;
            for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){

                if(names[i] == name){
                    inputIsAssociation = true;
                }

                var value = progressiveDisclosure.serializeArray().filter(function(input){
                    return input.name == names[i];
                })[0].value;

                if(values[i].indexOf('!') > -1 && values[i].replace('!','') !== value){
                    valid = true;
                } else if(values[i].indexOf('!') > -1 && values[i].replace('!','')  == value){
                    valid = false;
                    if(!matchAll){
                        break;
                    }
                } else if(values[i] == value){
                    valid = true;
                    if(!matchAll){
                        break;
                    }
                } else if(matchAll){
                     valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!inputIsAssociation){
                return;
            }

            if(valid){
                $(node).show();
            } else if(inputIsAssociation) {
                $(node).hide();
            }

        });

    }

$.each(associatedListeners, function(index, node){
    var $node = $(node),
        opts = $node.data('props');
    node.associationFor = $node.data('for').split(',');
    node.associationValue = $node.data('value').split(',');
    if(opts){
        node.associationOpts = opts.split(',');
    }
});

associatedHandlers.on('change', this, function(e){
    toggleAssociatedListeners(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the hide all show what you want but with a plus try making up names from the original selectors therefore:

```
$('select').change(){
     $('.divclass').hide();//which youll have to add
     var id = $(this).val(); //or 
              $(this).find('selected').val() 
    //not sure which works for selects
     id=id.replace('design','')
     //obviously you need a replace for this specific example('design','');
     $('#static-website-'+id).show();
}
```

In a few words the ids you want to show and the options or values ae related to the ids

Comment: This is one is really helpful. But how do i hide rest of the div when once is SHOW?

Comment: Give them all the same class and differentiate them with ids. Apply styles with ids so make them all $('.divclass') or class='hideable' o I don't know I did something like this some days ago check goumedical.com 's source code

Answer (score -1):

You can hide all , and show what you want.

```
    function showD(whatYouWantShow){

    //hide all  $(".mydiv").hide();
    //show whatYouWantShow   $("#d1").show();
    }

<div class=mydiv id="d1"></div>
<div class=mydiv id="d2"></div>
<div class=mydiv id="d3"></div>
```

Comment: i dont want to control the individual div....is there any logical way of doing this?

Comment: You can call function "showD" in selectbox onchange ( with parameter ) , it is not long way i think.